# Is there a better way to " Select non self mapping elements from a list of rules"?

Tags: functions, pattern-matching

Is there a better way to get the non self mapping list of rules from the list of rules

```
abc = {a -> a, b -> c, d -> d, e -> f};
```

To

```
{b -> c, e -> f}
```

I tried this way

```
ClearAll[Evaluate[StringJoin[Context[], "*"]]]
Needs["Utilities`CleanSlate`"]; 
CleanSlate[]; 
ClearInOut[];  

abc = {a -> a, b -> c, d -> d, e -> f};  

f1[x_] := If[x[[1]] == x[[2]], 
    False, True, True];  

f1 /@ abc  

Select[abc, f1[#1] & ]
```

Got the output as

```
{b -> c, e -> f}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select[Apply[UnsameQ]] @ abc
```

> ```
> {b -> c, e -> f}
> ```

Also

```
Select[# =!= Reverse@# &]@abc

DeleteCases[a_ -> a_] @ abc

ReplaceAll[Rule[a_, a_] :> Nothing] @ abc

Cases[Except[a_ -> a_]] @ abc (* thanks: @march *)
```

all give `{b -> c, e -> f}`.

Comment: `Cases[abc, Except[x_ -> x_]]`.